# Losing UI functionality while using the Background Worker

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, wcf, backgroundworker

I am quite new with using different threads and using the `BackgroundWorker`, so I do not fully understand everything yet. I have posted all the coding that I have from the client side of the program below.

***The problem*** that I have is that even though I use the `BackgroundWorker`, I still lose functionality of all of the UI while I load data from my WCF service to my WPF client application. It takes about 2-3 minutes to load the data(about +- 1500 lines of data), so it makes for a really bad user experience.

Is there any obvious thing that I might be missing to get the UI working while the data loads into the `datagrid`? Any advice would be appreciated, thank you! :)

**Updated Code:**

```
public partial class pgSysproStock : Window
{
    public pgSysproStock()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SysproStock.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
        dgSysproStock.IsEnabled = false;

        worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private readonly BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

    private async void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        using (TruckServiceClient TSC = new TruckServiceClient())
        {
            List<AllStock> allStock = new List<AllStock>();
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                prgStockProgress.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }));
            foreach (var item in await TSC.GetSysproStockAsync())
                allStock.Add(new AllStock
                {
                    Id = item.Id,
                    StockCode = item.StockCode,
                    Description = item.Description,
                    ConvFactAltUom = item.ConvFactAltUom,
                    ConvMulDiv = item.ConvMulDiv,
                    ConvFactOthUom = item.ConvFactOthUom,
                    MulDiv = item.MulDiv,
                    Mass = item.Mass,
                    Updated_Supplier = item.Updated_Supplier,
                    CycleCount = item.CycleCount,
                    ProductClass = item.ProductClass.ToString(),
                    UnitCost = item.UnitCost,
                    Discount = item.Discount,
                    Warehouse = item.Warehouse,
                    MinimumStock = item.MinimumStock,
                    MaximumStock = item.MaximumStock,
                    StockForNow = item.StockForNow,
                    CoilWidth = item.CoilWidth,
                    SheetCoilLength = item.SheetCoilLength,
                    MaterialThickness = item.MaterialThickness
                });
            e.Result = allStock.ToArray();
        }
    }

    private void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.prgStockProgress.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

    private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {            
        dgSysproStock.ItemsSource = (AllStock[])e.Result;
        dgSysproStock.IsEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I've also removed the `async` & `await` from the method in my coding, but the data still doesn't seem to come through.

I've added a *breakpoint* here: `foreach (var item in await TSC.GetSysproStockAsync())` and I can't get past the `TSC.GetSysproStock())` code. Why is it doing this?

Comment: this is the operation that blocks your UI: `dgSysproStock.ItemsSource = (allStock.ToArray());`.

Comment: You can't mix async/await with background worker. `worker_DoWork` can't be async. I'd say just throw away the BGW and work with async await alone.

Comment: At the first glance it seems wrong to use async/await within the BackgroundWorker.

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel - Thank you for the comment! :) If I remove the `BackgroundWorker` I won't be able to use my UI, as it will be disabled while I am loading the data from the WCF service.

Comment: There is no need for the BackgroundWorker if you use the async/await correctly. The await keyword causes the method execution to be split across threads, with the rest of the method acting as a callback.

Comment: As @GlenThomas said, You don't need *BackgroundWorker if you use the async/await correctly.* UI will not  be frozen.

Answer (score 2):

Using the async/await correctly:

```
    public pgSysproStock()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SysproStock.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;

        this.UpdateStockAsync();
    }

    private async void UpdateStockAsync()
    {
        dgSysproStock.IsEnabled = false;

        using (TruckServiceClient TSC = new TruckServiceClient())
        {
            var allStock = await TSC.GetSysproStockAsync().ToArray();

            dgSysproStock.ItemsSource = allStock.Select(item =>
                        new AllStock
                            {
                                Id = item.Id,
                                StockCode = item.StockCode,
                                Description = item.Description,
                                ConvFactAltUom = item.ConvFactAltUom,
                                ConvMulDiv = item.ConvMulDiv,
                                ConvFactOthUom = item.ConvFactOthUom,
                                MulDiv = item.MulDiv,
                                Mass = item.Mass,
                                Updated_Supplier = item.Updated_Supplier,
                                CycleCount = item.CycleCount,
                                ProductClass = item.ProductClass.ToString(),
                                UnitCost = item.UnitCost,
                                Discount = item.Discount,
                                Warehouse = item.Warehouse,
                                MinimumStock = item.MinimumStock,
                                MaximumStock = item.MaximumStock,
                                StockForNow = item.StockForNow,
                                CoilWidth = item.CoilWidth,
                                SheetCoilLength = item.SheetCoilLength,
                                MaterialThickness = item.MaterialThickness
                        }).ToArray();

        dgSysproStock.IsEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks again for the second answer Glen. The data loads fine with the new coding that you gave, except I'm back at square one where all of the UI is still disabled/nonresponsive :(

Comment: But thanks for trying to help me. ;) I will go and ask a new question on this in a while after I've done some research.

Comment: I think the problem might be that GetSysproStockAsync uses the yield keyword to return an iterator. Try adding .ToArray() as in my updated answer and see if this helps.

Comment: Hi Glen. `var allStock = await TSC.GetSysproStockAsync().ToArray();` gives me the error: _does not contain a definition for 'ToArray' and no extension method 'ToArray'_

Comment: You might need to add "using System.Linq;" to the code file

Comment: I also do use `using System.Linq`. It's giving me the same error

Comment: Ah of course, GetSysproStockAsync will return a Task<T>. I'm not sure how best to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

This is not how the BackgroundWorker should be used. Try passing the data through to the RunWorkerCompleted event handler and update the UI from there.

Remove this:

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
{
    dgSysproStock.ItemsSource = (allStock.ToArray());
    dgSysproStock.IsEnabled = true;
}));
```

In the DoWork event handler, set the Result to your data:

```
e.Result = allStock.ToArray();
```

Then in the RunWorkerCompleted event handler:

```
dgSysproStock.ItemsSource = (AllSTock[])e.Result;
dgSysproStock.IsEnabled = true;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and effort Glen. :D I've updated the code like you suggested and I can now use all of my UI elements(thanks), but now for some reason the data doesn't seem to load into my datagrid. Might the problem be at `e.Result = allStock.ToArray();` at the end of my DoWork event?